# What is xdg-open?

Tags: google-chrome, xdg-open

I tried downloading roblox and it worked fine I double clicked it. It takes me to the website. But when I launch a game it doesn't say Open Roblox Launcher chrome just says xdg-open and nothing happens.

Comment: This command will tell you more ```xdg-open --manual```

Answer (score 5):

The xdg-open is used to open a url or file in the your preferred program. Use `xdg-open --manual` to learn more.

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a URL is
> provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web browser. If a file
> is provided the file will be opened in the preferred application for files of
> that type. xdg-open supports file, ftp, http and https URLs.

> xdg-open is for use inside a desktop session only. It is not recommended to use
> xdg-open as root.

Comment: Link to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html would be useful too.